# How to manage processing a list of strings expanded from another object?

Tags: powershell

So, I've keep having trouble with tasks like this:

```
$fileNames = Get-ChildItem -Path . -Filter "*.*" `
    | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

$fileNames.GetType()
```

I'd expect output to be string[], but it is object[].

Even worse, if I then try to manipulate the file names:

```
$fileNames = Get-ChildItem -Path . -Filter "*.*" `
    | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name `
    | Select-Object { "$_" -replace '^.*deploy\.log\.\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\.', '' }
```

I'd expect again string[]. Instead I get some weird hashtable that has as a key the regex.

In both cases, its doing what I expect, just wrapping it up in objects.

What are the rules here? I can I just manipulate a list of strings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your last pipeline element, use `ForEach-Object` instead of `Select-Object`

```
$fileNames = Get-ChildItem -Path . -Filter "*.*" `
    | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name `
    | ForEach-Object { "$_" -replace '^.*deploy\.log\.\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\.', '' }
```

---

You can skip the `Select-Object -Expand` part altogether if you wish:

```
$fileNames = Get-ChildItem -Filter *.* | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Name -replace '^.*deploy\.log\.\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\.', ''
}
```

Comment: So, ForEach-Object is more like map. I.e. it applies a function to each item and returns a list? Instead of like Linq's ForEach that takes an action on each item, but doesn't return anything?

Comment: `ForEach-Object` is like a `map` function, yes. Returning items from each iteration is optional

Answer (score 5):

The result of your first code snippet is a generic array (hence its type says `Object[]`), but the elements are actually strings. If for some reason you need the type to be `string[]` you can simply cast the variable to that type:

```
[string[]]$filenames = Get-ChildItem ... | Select-Object -Expand Name
```

Normally that shouldn't be necessary, though.

In your second code snippet you're probably confusing `Select-Object` with `ForEach-Object` (see [Mathias' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40731475/1630171)). Instead of using a `ForEach-Object` loop you could also use the `-replace` operator directly on the expanded names:

```
$filenames = (Get-ChildItem ... | Select-Object -Expand Name) -replace '^.*deploy\.log\.\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\.', ''
```

Comment: Thanks. So the -replace works on a list? And applies that to each item and return a list?